# Finding $E(X\mid \min(X,Y))$ where $X,Y$ are independent $U(0,1)$ variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables, uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. I have to compute $E(X\mid\min(X,Y)=t)$, but in very educational way, I mean, I have to explain it to my students and I would rather prefer do not use very advanced methods. Is it possible? I was trying to compute common distribution function and then take its density, but I think that density does not exist. So, is there any easy, FORMAL way?

Comment: What do your students know? It's pretty easy to calculate the joint distribution $(X,\min (X,Y))$ if your students know about general measures. It doesn't have density, though, as you say.

Comment: Okay, assume that I computed joint distribution and it has no density. How to compute conditional expectation?

Comment: Well... you don't need a density, you just need a Markov kernel. If $(X,Y)\sim \mu$ and $\mu(A\times B)=\int_B \nu_y(A)\textrm{d} \gamma(y)$ for some appropriate measure $\gamma$ and family of measure $\nu_y$, then $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} x\textrm{d}\nu_Y$ by exactly the same argument that works in the density case.

Comment: In your case, if we denote by $\lambda^2$ the 2-dimensional Lesbegue measure and $\lambda_{\Delta}$ the Lesbegue measure on the diagonal lifted from $\mathbb{R}$. Then your measure is $\mu=1_{x\geq y} 1_{0\leq x\leq 1} \textrm{d}\lambda^2+(1-x)\textrm{d}\lambda$, which *does* have a Markov kernel decomposition with $\nu_y= \frac{1}{2}\delta_y+\frac{1}{2(1-y)}\cdot 1_{[y,1]}\textrm{d}\lambda $.

Comment: Okay, I agree, but the problem is how to find that $\gamma$ measure and the family of $\nu_y$?

Comment: In your case, $\lambda_{\Delta}$ and $\lambda^2$ are singular, so $\mu$ has density with respect to $\lambda^2+\lambda_{\Delta}$ given by $(1_{1\geq x>y\geq 0}+1_{x=y}(1-x))\textrm{d}(\lambda^2+\lambda_{\Delta})$. In general, I don't know if there's any way around regular conditional probability measures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try drawing a square something like this as the joint distribution is uniform on the square

[image]

The condition $\min(X,Y)=t$ corresponds to points on the orange and red lines (orange for $t=X \le Y$ and red for $t=Y \le X$

Conditioned on this, the probability $P(X=t \mid \min(X,Y)=t) =\frac12$ by symmetry, and if not then $X$ is uniformly distributed between $t$ and $1$ so with density $f(x)=\frac{1}{2(1-t)}\mathbf 1_{t \lt x \lt 1}$

This makes the conditional expected value $\mathbb E[X \mid \min(X,Y)=t ]=\frac12 t + \frac12\left(\frac{t +1}{2}\right) = \frac 34 t +\frac14$

This turns out to be formal, with the corresponding conditional CDF $$\mathbb P(X \le x \mid \min(X,Y)=t )=\left\{ 
\begin{matrix}0 & \text{ for } x\lt t \\\frac12 & \text{ for } x= t \\  \frac{x+1-2t}{2-2t} & \text{ for } t \lt x\le 1 \\  1 & \text{ for } 1 \lt x \end{matrix} \right.$$

Comment: Very clear and transparent explanation! Thank you!

Comment: Thank You very much!

Comment: @StubbornAtom You may be correct, but could you indicate which ones?

Comment: @StubbornAtom $P(X\le t \mid \min(X,Y)=t) =\frac12$ is correct, but since $P(X\lt t \mid \min(X,Y)=t) =0$ that would suggest to me $P(X= t \mid \min(X,Y)=t) =\frac12$ too

Comment: @StubbornAtom On the density, you have to stretch a probability of $\frac12$ uniformly over an interval of length $1-t$, which I would have thought would make the density $\frac{1/2}{1-t} =\frac{1}{2(1-t)}$

Comment: It's fine. Thanks for the explanation. I misunderstood.

Comment: Hey, so is that task an example of The Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem where $P=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{t}+\mu$, where $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @mwrooo I suspect writing that expression might confuse your students (why not $\frac{1}{2}\delta_{t}+\frac12 \mu$?), but yes, the conditional distribution for $X$ is made up of a discrete part (in fact a single point) and an absolutely continuous part (the uniform distribution).

Comment: Of course, it would be better to write $\frac{1}{2}\mu$. I think that the whole task would be confusing for my students because they are used to the density function.

Comment: I am wondering is there a chance to do the same with for example exponential distribution i.e. stretch it in some way on shorter interval than $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @mwrooo A similar argument applies.  Suppose the rate is $\lambda$.  Using the memoryless property of the exponential you can say that conditioned on the minimum being $\min(X,Y)=t$ you have an expectation of $\frac12 t + \frac12\left(t+\frac1\lambda\right) = t+\frac{1}{2\lambda}$.  Again the conditional probability of $X=t$ is $\frac12$ while for $x \gt t$ the conditional density is $\frac12\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-t)}$

Comment: Great, I have one more question: what about $X,Y$ exponentially distributed and computing $E(\min(X,Y)|\max(X,Y))$? (You are great teacher, so I am taking my chance ;)) )

Comment: @mwrooo - I would guess $\mathbb E[\min(X,Y)\mid \max(X,Y) =s] = \int\limits_{t=0}^s \frac{t \lambda e^{-t\lambda}}{1-e^{-s\lambda}}\, dt = \frac{1-(1+s\lambda)e^{-s \lambda}}{\lambda\left(1-e^{-s \lambda}\right)}$